# Windows Clipboard won't preserve ASCII character

Tags: c++, c, ascii, special-characters, clipboard

I am writing a plugin for the TS3 Client, but I ran into an issue...

One of the channel names has a special sign (╠) in it, which is a special character from the extended ascii table I think.

When logging it INSIDE teamspeak, the character shows fine, but when trying to copy it to the windows clipboard using its C interface it returns a whole different character (â).

I have tried converting it to WCHAR after I read that the extended ascii table uses more bytes than the regular char, but that didn't work either.

I use the following code to copy the char* to the clipboard which I found somewhere and altered with some other code I found for using WCHAR:

```
void SaveClipboard(char* tx)
{
    WCHAR text[140];
    swprintf(text, 140, L"%hs", tx);

    if(OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        HGLOBAL global = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, 2 * (wcslen(text) + 1)); //text size + \0 character

        WCHAR* pchData;
        pchData = (WCHAR*)GlobalLock(global);
        wcscpy(pchData, text);
        GlobalUnlock(pchData);

        SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, global);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

Comment: The clipboard doesn't contain anything different. Whatever you're using to display it isn't configured to use the proper font. You need to use one that uses the ASCII (OEM) character set, such as the Terminal font on Windows.

Comment: The problem is, directly copying it from TS (using select and crtl + c) can show the character just fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's just `â` and not `â•`?

Comment: Duskwuff, for char you are correct, not for WCHAR though. Your comment seems like you understand why this is happening and how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: @JH_WK: You have to understand that ultimately, characters are numbers. Different character sets have different characters for the same number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wchar_t` is `UTF-16` encoded, but the data you get is `UTF-8` encoded. You don't convert between these two encodings, you simply reinterpret the bytes.

Looking at the code points for those characters it should become obvious what's happening: The UTF-8 code point for `╠` is `0xE2 0x95 0xA0` and the UTF-16 code point for `â` is `0x00 0xE2`, while the UTF-16 code point for `╠` is `0x25 0x60`.

`swprintf(text, 140, L"%hs", tx);` <- This simply converts each `char` into a `wchar_t`, turning the 3 byte `UTF-8` code point `0xE2 0x95 0xA0` into three 2 byte `UTF-16` code points: `0x00 0xE2`, `0x00 0x95` and `0x00 0xA0`.

To get `0x25 0x60` from `0xE2 0x95 0xA0` you need to actually convert the data:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>> converter;
std::wstring text = converter.from_bytes(tx);
```

Alternatively, since you are using WINAPI already, you can use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar):

```
WCHAR text[140];
int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, tx, -1, (LPWSTR)text, 140);
```

Comment: Nah. We'll just anonymously downvote you and leave no hints as to why. Mu. Mhuhu. Mhuhahahahahaha! Power! Unlimited power!

Comment: That worked, thanks! But for some odd reason the WINAPI solution threw a compiler error. Appearently the function doesn't like a pointer to an WCHAR array, but rather wants an allocated WCHAR* pointer.
`WCHAR* text = (WCHAR*)malloc(140 * sizeof(WCHAR));`
`MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, tx, -1, text, 140);`

Comment: @JH_WK No need to dynamically allocate it. Removing the `&` should suffice. I updated my answer.